# Telegraf Data Collection - How to select specific Fields for input

Tags: telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

The title is pretty much my question - I'm new to Telegraf and slowly getting to grips with how to run it and specify log files, archiving processes, etc etc.

One of the, IMO very simple, tasks I have is to specify the metrics collected. For example, only to collect CPU-busy per CPU ID. But when I run my basic config (***telegraf --config telegraf.conf --once***), it collects literally every field per the input requested.

Is there a way to tell Telegraf to only collect specific fields per the input? My Telegraf.conf CPU setup is as below:

```
[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = false
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false
  core_tags = false
```

Cheers very much in advance, Vinny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegraf configuration provides support for [metric-filtering](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.23/configuration/#metric-filtering).
For your use case, you may try **fieldpass** or **fielddrop** whichever is useful.

Short description about:

**fieldpass**: An array of glob pattern strings. Only fields whose field key matches a pattern in this list are emitted.

**fielddrop**: The inverse of fieldpass. Fields with a field key matching one of the patterns will be discarded from the point.

I assume that by cpu busy, you mean the percentage consumption by user level processes. In that case, your configuration becomes:

```
[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = false
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false
  core_tags = false
  fieldpass = ["usage_user"]
```

The above configuration will output only the usage by user level processes.

NOTE: By CPU busy, if you mean to collect system usage as well, add usage_system as well to the fieldpass array

If you would like to report the sum of all non-idle CPU states, you need to set `report_active = true` in the above configuration. To report only the active usage (sum of all non-idle CPU states), pass the `usage_active` in the **fieldpass** array as `fieldpass = ["usage_active"]`

If you wish to collect statistics of each cpu separately, set `percpu = true`